# Accessing remote web application using LogMeIn Hamachi2

Tags: vpn, logmein, hamachi

I am trying to remotely access a web application hosted on the office LAN.

I have setup LogMeIN Hamachi and I can connect to an office machine and see shared resources (folders and printers) on that machine.

I selected a Hub-and-spoke network and made the machine with the web app the hub.

While in the office I type http://192.168.1.6:8080/mituz_oc in my browser to get access to the web app.

However, when I try to do the same remotely I get the message "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.6:8080."

So I see that the IP address to the computer I have VPN-ed to is 5.14.212.196 and so I try to gain access to the web app by replacing the office LAN's IP with the Hamachi IP (I can only post one hyperlink hence the verbose alternative )

I get the same error message as before, only this time with the HAMACHI IP address.

I can access all the shared resources but can not access the web app.

Is it possible to do what  am attempting - remotely access a web application on office server?

If so what am I doing wrong / not doing ?

TIA.

Clemens

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if your Windows Personal Firewall setting blocks connections from Hamachi's 5.x.x.x IP address ranges.

2) Check if your Web Server listens on 5.x.x.x.  You can find it out by this command:

netstat -na

Look for local address of "0.0.0.0:8080" which is in the state of "LISTENING".

3) Replace Hamachi with different VPN provider, like www.remobo.com

(Disclosure: I work for the Remobo team)